# Update(fetch + reset) a branch A from remote without a pull after a fetch?

Tags: git, git-pull, git-reset, git-fetch

On my repo I have a `master` and `dev` branches.

When I make changes to the `dev`, and the `master` have new commits I do a `git fetch` to check first if there is some new commit on the `master` branch.

If there is some new commit i can do a `git pull origin master:master` to pull the master branch without checking it out, but with that I have 2 fetches to the repository (One during the `git fetch`, and other one during the `git pull`).

The other option is to do as follows:

```
git checkout dev
git fetch (fetched a commit from origin/master)
git stash
git checkout master
git reset --hard origin/master
git checkout dev
git stash pop
(do commit, merge, etc)
```

I want to do something like this:

```
git checkout dev
git fetch (fetched a commit from origin/master)
git (command to update the master branch to the last commit where origin/master is pointing)
(do commit, merge, etc)
```

I tried a `git reset --hard origin master:master` but it gave me a `fatal: Path 'master' does not exist in 'origin/master'`

So, what is that magical git command to repoint/reset a branch that my HEAD is not actually pointing?

Comment: Consider simply *deleting* your `master`. You can then use `origin/master` to look at commits after any `git fetch` operation. You can also not bother deleting your `master`, but also not bother *using* it, while you're on `dev`: just use your `origin/master` whenever you need to do something with their latest commit.

Comment: But I can merge to the origin/master?

Comment: No, for that you'll need to `git checkout master` (which will create it matching up with `origin/master` it if you've deleted it), then run `git merge --ff-only` if you didn't delete it.  It's now ready for: `git merge dev` and then `git push origin master`.

Answer (score 0):

```
git checkout dev
git fetch origin master:master
```

The second command fetches new commits from remote `origin` branch
`master` and updates the local `master` to where `origin/master` is
pointing now.

Comment: I do know that (but i use a `git pull origin master:master`), I am trying to find a command that does just the part of "and updates the local master to where origin/master is pointing now"

Comment: `git fetch origin master:master` is exactly that.